# How can I send an empty node as part of a SOAP request in mule studio?

Tags: soap, mule, mule-studio

I'm trying to configure a flow in mule studio using the Web Services Connector. The SOAP body the endpoint is expecting looks like:

```
<soapenv:Body>
  <v4:readFields>
     <filter>
        <type>?</type>
        <id>?</id>
        <name>
           <operator>?</operator>
           <value>?</value>
        </name>
     </filter>
     <pageNumber>?</pageNumber>
  </v4:readFields>
</soapenv:Body>
```

The `<filter>` node itself is required, but the contents are optional, so I'd like to get my flow to send a body like:

```
<soapenv:Body>
  <v4:readFields>
     <filter />
     <pageNumber>1</pageNumber>
  </v4:readFields>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Is there a way to set up the message payload to send this request?

Running Anypoint Studio 5.1.0, Mule ESB 3.6.
My current flow config:

```
<flow name="GetFieldInfo">
    <http:listener config-ref="localhost" path="/fields" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <enricher source="#[payload]" target="#[flowVars.sessionId]" doc:name="GetSessionId">
        <flow-ref name="GetSessionId" doc:name="Login"/>
    </enricher>
    <data-mapper:transform config-ref="Xml_loginResponse__To_Xml_sessionHeader_" input-ref="#[flowVars[&quot;sessionId&quot;]]" target="#[message.outboundProperties[&quot;soap.sessionHeader&quot;]]" doc:name="Set Session Header"/>
    <ws:consumer config-ref="BrontoAPI" operation="readFields" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
    <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
</flow>
```

Comment: Mule version ? Flow config ?

Comment: Added version and current config to question.

Comment: Thanks! It's really hard to know what's going on here, especially without seeing what's the message payload right when execution hits `ws:consumer`. What does Mule send currently? A `filter` element with empty child elements?

Comment: With that config it breaks because the payload is null. (the enricher and datamapper in the flow are only touching the soap header, not the message payload). If I use a variable->datamapper to set pageNumber in the soap body, it will break with "unable to verify parameter filter". The debugger just displays my payloads as byte arrays, so I have no idea what is actually going on.

Comment: What does nullify the payload? If you add a `logger` before the `ws:consumer` does it log the payload as null?

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of mule parse template to send static xml with variable data

sample :

```
<soapenv:Body>
 <v4:readFields>
 <filter />
 <pageNumber>#[payload]</pageNumber>
 </v4:readFields>
</soapenv:Body>
```

you can find the documentation here https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Parse+Template+Reference